# How to allow c printf to print in ipython notebook in cython cell?

Tags: c, cython, jupyter-notebook

```
%%cython
from libc.stdio cimport printf
def test():
    printf('abc')
```

If I run `test()`, it doesn't print anything.

Currently I am doing something stupid as:

```
cdef char s[80]
sprintf(s, 'something')
print s
```

What's a better way to use `printf` in cython? Why doesn't it print?

Comment: Currently, IPython only captures and displays the output at Python-level, have a look at this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1230) for a discussion about this problem. However I don't know where the output goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`wurlitzer`](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer) package to capture C-level stdout / stderr and redirect it to IPython.

For example, include the following code blocks in your Jupyter notebook:

```py
%load_ext Cython
%load_ext wurlitzer
```

```py
%%cython
from libc.stdio cimport printf
def test():
    printf('abc')
```

```py
test()
# prints "abc"
```

Comment: wurlitzer seems only to work for Unix-system, as it uses `fcntl` which is Unix-only library:(

Comment: doesn't seem to work with `printf()` in `source.c` and `cdef extern from "source.c"` in `%%cython` cell.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Output will be printed in your terminal (console) running Jupyter notebook. not sure how to display it in Jupyter though.