# "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" when running %%cython in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, cython

I have installed cython with conda

[cython installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IeKGC.png)

After restarting the kernel, I have also loaded it without error using `%reload_ext Cython`.

However, when I try to run the following code

```
%%cython

import numpy as np

cdef int a = 0
cdef int g[10]
cdef int i

for i in range(10):
    g[i] = a
    a += i
print(g)
```

I get the error `command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`.

I am fairly new to cython and have no idea on how to solve this or even what questions to search for.

The complete error log:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
DistutilsExecError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py in _compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    117             self.spawn(compiler_so + cc_args + [src, '-o', obj] +
--> 118                        extra_postargs)
    119         except DistutilsExecError as msg:

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py in spawn(self, cmd)
    908     def spawn(self, cmd):
--> 909         spawn(cmd, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    910 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/spawn.py in spawn(cmd, search_path, verbose, dry_run)
     35     if os.name == 'posix':
---> 36         _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, dry_run=dry_run)
     37     elif os.name == 'nt':

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/spawn.py in _spawn_posix(cmd, search_path, verbose, dry_run)
    158                           "command %r failed with exit status %d"
--> 159                           % (cmd, exit_status))
    160             elif os.WIFSTOPPED(status):

DistutilsExecError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

CompileError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-16f694f6508b> in <module>
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('cython', '', '\nimport numpy as np\n\ncdef int a = 0\ncdef int g[10]\ncdef int i\n\nfor i in range(10):\n    g[i] = a\n    a += i\nprint(g)\n')

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py in run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2357             if getattr(fn, "needs_local_scope", False):
   2358                 kwargs['local_ns'] = self.user_ns
-> 2359 
   2360             with self.builtin_trap:
   2361                 args = (magic_arg_s, cell)

</Users/w849277/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/decorator.py:decorator-gen-128> in cython(self, line, cell)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/magic.py in <lambda>(f, *a, **k)
    185     # but it's overkill for just that one bit of state.
    186     def magic_deco(arg):
--> 187         call = lambda f, *a, **k: f(*a, **k)
    188 
    189         if callable(arg):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/IpythonMagic.py in cython(self, line, cell)
    331         extension = None
    332         if need_cythonize:
--> 333             extensions = self._cythonize(module_name, code, lib_dir, args, quiet=args.quiet)
    334             if extensions is None:
    335                 # Compilation failed and printed error message

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/Cython/Build/IpythonMagic.py in _build_extension(self, extension, lib_dir, temp_dir, pgo_step_name, quiet)
    441                 force=True,
    442             )
--> 443             if args.language_level is not None:
    444                 assert args.language_level in (2, 3)
    445                 opts['language_level'] = args.language_level

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py in run(self)
    338 
    339         # Now actually compile and link everything.
--> 340         self.build_extensions()
    341 
    342     def check_extensions_list(self, extensions):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py in build_extensions(self)
    447             self._build_extensions_parallel()
    448         else:
--> 449             self._build_extensions_serial()
    450 
    451     def _build_extensions_parallel(self):

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py in _build_extensions_serial(self)
    472         for ext in self.extensions:
    473             with self._filter_build_errors(ext):
--> 474                 self.build_extension(ext)
    475 
    476     @contextlib.contextmanager

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/command/build_ext.py in build_extension(self, ext)
    532                                          debug=self.debug,
    533                                          extra_postargs=extra_args,
--> 534                                          depends=ext.depends)
    535 
    536         # XXX outdated variable, kept here in case third-part code

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/ccompiler.py in compile(self, sources, output_dir, macros, include_dirs, debug, extra_preargs, extra_postargs, depends)
    572             except KeyError:
    573                 continue
--> 574             self._compile(obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    575 
    576         # Return *all* object filenames, not just the ones we just built.

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/distutils/unixccompiler.py in _compile(self, obj, src, ext, cc_args, extra_postargs, pp_opts)
    118                        extra_postargs)
    119         except DistutilsExecError as msg:
--> 120             raise CompileError(msg)
    121 
    122     def create_static_lib(self, objects, output_libname,

CompileError: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Also, my mac is updated to 10.15.3 Catalina while my friend's mac that stayed as 10.14.6 Mojave ran the same code without any problems. I have heard compatibility issues with Anaconda when Catalina first came out, but I don't know if this has anything to do with my error.

Comment: gcc will have written an error message to stderr before it exited. Those errors are where you need to start.

Comment: The meaningful error message was printed to stderr as Charles Duffy already said, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/57726729/5769463

Answer (score 0):

Just answering my own question so I can close this.

Thank you for two comments on my question! I was able to locate the meaningful answer in my terminal according to the answer provided here: [What does CompileError/LinkerError: "command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1" mean, when running %%cython-magic cell in IPython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57726729/what-does-compileerror-linkererror-command-gcc-failed-with-exit-status-1-me)

It turns out the error was

```
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

which simply needed to be resolved by running this code in the terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

For a more detailed solution to the missing `xcrun` problem, check here https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a